# “Google script” take up a lot of CPU resources on my cloud server

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Resource usage image

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsxez.png]

How to reduce the resource usage of these processes?

I had tried upgrade vCPU, but no change in the proportion of resources occupied.

Thank you very much!

Comment: They should use no significant CPU. Did you install the updates?

Answer (score 1):

The top manual explains why more CPUs does not change the percentage. On Linux so the procps-ng version:

> ### %CPU -- CPU Usage
>
> The task's share of the elapsed CPU time since the last screen update,
>   expressed as  a  per‐ centage of total CPU time.
>
> In  a  true  SMP  environment,  if  a  process is multi-threaded and
>   top is not operating in Threads mode, amounts greater than 100% may be
>   reported.  You toggle Threads mode  with  the `H' interactive command.
>
> Also for multi-processor environments, if Irix mode is Off, top will
>   operate in Solaris mode where a task's cpu usage  will  be  divided 
>   by  the  total  number  of  CPUs.   You  toggle Irix/Solaris modes
>   with the `I' interactive command.

So, that is percent of *one* logical CPU, not all.

---

24% of a CPU seems like a lot for some background processes, time sync and directory services and the like. Do you see it when you launch a fresh instance?

Profile it to see what it really is doing, because [CPU utilization is wrong](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-05-09/cpu-utilization-is-wrong.html) (at least, misleading). On Linux start with `perf top`.